# Google Play Games - getting access token returns internal error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I'm integrating Google Play Games Unity sdk, logging in with google account and getting user id or image are all ok, but token can't be get.

I called this method:

```
PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetServerAuthCode();
```

Error from logcat:

```
*** [Play Games Plugin DLL]  ERROR: Error loading server auth code: ERROR_INTERNAL
```

Anybody know where is wrong?

Comment: Maybe this is because the webClientId being passed in is for an application that is not a web app that is linked to the game configuration on the Play Game Console. I'd suggest checking that the client id matches (and that it does not have any leading/trailing spaces, etc.)

Comment: I followed [link](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling) to create clientId, `"I don't use any Google APIs in my game yet"` is chosen at Step2, project will be created at Developer Console, then `"Link an Android app"` at Step3, ClientId will be created at `"Authorize your app"`, I didn't create any clientId by myself manually.

Comment: I checked this clientId in Developer Console, the type of clientId is displayed as Android, do I need to create a new clientId of a  web app?

Comment: Yes, the web client id passed in needs to be a web app type.

Comment: Thank you very much, Clayton, it works.